# C# 8 .NET core 3.1 nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-8.0

Почитал я про `C# 8`. Прочитал то, что ссылочные типы по умолчанию не могут хранить `null`. Зашел в visual studio. Написал:

```
string f = null;
f = null;
Console.WriteLine(f);
```

А оно компилируется...

В настройках проекта стоит `.NET core 3.1`, а это значит что версия `C#` - `восьмая`.

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не ссылочные, а типы значений. Ссылочные на то и ссылочные, что могут ни на что не ссылаться (null) в отличии от значения.

Comment: Компилироваться оно будет в любом случае, только выдаст предупреждение в случае директивы `#nullable enable`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников значение никогда не могло на null. А в c#8 добавили то что ссылочные не могут ссылаться на null

Comment: Я так понимаю добавили просто контракт, который кроме варнинга ни на что не влияет. «Физика» осталась прежней. См комментарий @SmorcIRL

Comment: @АртёмОконечников к сожалению он прав( Или к счастью.....

Comment: @Lofectr в этом мире есть совместимость и легаси. Нельзя вот так взять и переделать язык. Поезд с нулами уже давно ушел.

Comment: По идее дожен быть способ поднять "опасность" этого варнинга до уровня ошибки, ну или компилировать с флагом на то чтобы не пускало с варнингами

Comment: Да, есть такое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194983/how-to-treat-all-c-sharp-8-nullable-reference-warnings-as-errors

Comment: Минусующие вообще про c#8 не в курсе?

Comment: @4per походу(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию проверка на nullable отключена. Её можно включить несколькими способами.

[Первый](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). В начале файла добавляем директиву `#nullable`:

```
#nullable enable
```

[Второй](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types). В файл конфига вставляем опцию:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Также можно задать эту опцию в командной строке: [-nullable (C# Compiler Options)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nullable-compiler-option).

---

Для чего сделан первый способ, если можно задать настройку сразу для всего проекта? Для постепенной миграции большой кодовой базы на nullable-типы. [Tutorial: Migrate existing code with nullable reference types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references).

---

Чтобы дополнительно обезопаситься от ошибок, можно в настройках проекта на вкладке Build установить переключатель Treat warnings as errors в значение All или Specific warnings и задать там нужные коды ошибок.

Comment: Всё верно, но чтобы сделать nullable как ошибку, надо в файл конфига написать `<WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>`